# Setgt and Readpe not fetching any records?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am writing following code. Logically some records should be fetched but it is not. Code is given below-

```
uweid = 1;                            
uwefname = 'VIKASH';                  
setgt(e) (uweid:uwefname) rempdtl2;
readpe(e) (uweid:uwefname) rempdtl2;  
dow not %eof(EMPDTL2) and not %error; 
  uwaddress = eaddress;               
  readpe(e) (uweid:uwefname) rempdtl2;
enddo;
```

Source of the File is as follows-

```
A          R REMPDTL2          
A            EID            5P 
A            EFNAME        10A 
A            EADDRESS      30A 
A            ECNTCT        10P 
A          K EID               
A          K EFNAME            
A          K ECNTCT
```

Date in the table is as follows-

```
EID   EFNAME      EADDRESS                               ECNTCT
  1   VIKASH      CHOUK                                   9,532
  2   ANKUR       DELHI                                   9,415
  3   RAVI        NOIDA                                   9,696
  1   VIKASH      Lko                                     9,540
  1   VIKASH      BAREILY                                 9,530
  1   VIKASH      AGRA                                    9,525
  1   VIKASH      Lko                                     9,540
```

Logically records should be fetched. But it is not happening. Please help me to understand this situation.

Comment: show the source for the file.

Comment: I have added the source.

Comment: Nothing is jumping out at me.  Are you sure you're opening the file you think you are?  Does `WRKF EMPDTL2` show more than one?  If you run it in debug, stop of the first executable line and check the file that is actually opened.  Are you running the RPG directly or is it being called from a CL program?

Comment: What are the definitions of 'uweid` and `uwefname`?

Comment: The code works fine for me when I use the example data. Please explain **how you know** that `records should be fetched but it is not`. From what I see, records are indeed fetched.

Comment: Definition of uweid and uwefname is as follows-                        d uweid           s              5p 0                                                    d uwefname        s             10a

Comment: Still looking for a clear description of **how you know** that `records should be fetched but it is not`. Explanation of your debug method can help us understand your problem, especially since there doesn't seem to be one.

Comment: I think, In this example when I use setgt, pointer will set after the last record having **EID = 1** and **EFNAME = VIKASH.** There are total 5 records with **EID = 1** and **EFNAME = VIKASH.** SO while using READPE it should fetch records similar **EID = 1** and **EFNAME = VIKASH.**

Comment: Oh... I got the problem. Actually this code was some portion of my program.I was using this file previously also in the same program. Due to this it would have got EOF condition so my code was not working. I made a separate program and now this code is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

When I read a file with "readp" or "readpe", I always make a "setgt *hival xxx" before.

Try it.